# Passing a VARIANT from mac OS X Excel 2011 VBA to c++

Tags: c++, excel, macos, vba, variant

I am under mac OS X, and using excel-2011 vba. I know how to pass various types from VBA to c++ and inversely, mainly thanks to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/205277).

Now, I would like to know if it is possible to somehow pass a VBA variant to c++ (I am using gcc 5.2). Of course, there's no `VARIANT` in gcc but, after all, `VARIANT` is "just" a union. (The optimistic guy.) Have you guys heared about classes mimicking microsoft's `VARIANT` and allowing to achieve this ? (In the first time, I could accept to forget about `IUnknown` and `IDispatch` !)

I am aware of [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/com-interop/), and looked what I could get from it, as they also have a `VARIANT`class, but I don't know if it wise. I looked for a document explaining in detail the object model of excel-2011 for mac, without any success.

*Precision.* I am not saying that microsoft's `VARIANT` is, under windows, the optimal way to exchange data between c++ and excel but, with COM and ATL and stuff, I am quite used to it and it works well for what I do, so I am trying to stick to something of the "same kind" under mac OS X. I may be wrong, but in this case, I would really like to know how I could do what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally opted for porting `VARIANT`to mac os x, see here :

[BSTR's and VARIANT's under... mac os x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35940136/bstrs-and-variants-under-mac-os-x)

where I described how I am now trying to do it.